# Overloading with either integer or double inputs java

Tags: java, overloading

The code I was asked to create overloaded methods with different parameters which finds the maximum values when given 3 integers or doubles.

I am not sure how to tell the main program to call the method for the integer values when given integers or to call the method for double values when given doubles.

Say, I was given (3.0, 2.0, 2.0), I want the max value as 3.0. I do not know how to call just the method for doubles.

Edit: The numbers have to be entered through the console. It is from here I do not know how to make the program choose a method.

```
public class NMax {

    public static int max(int a, int b, int c) {

    int max = 0;

    if (a>=b) {
        if (a>=c) {
        max=a;
        } else {
        max=c;
        }
    } else if (b>=a) {
        if (b>=c) {
        max=b;
        } else {
        max=c;
        }
    }
    return max;
    }

    public static double max(double a, double b, double c) {

    double max = 0;

    if (a>=b) {
        if (a>=c) {
        max=a;
        } else {
        max=c;
        }
    } else if (b>=a) {
        if (b>=c) {
        max=b;
        } else {
        max=c;
        }
    }
    return max;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double d = StdIn.readDouble();
    double e = StdIn.readDouble();
    double f = StdIn.readDouble();

    int a = StdIn.readInt();
    int b = StdIn.readInt();
    int c = StdIn.readInt();

    System.out.print(max(d, e, f));

    }
}
```

Comment: It's done automatically by the compiler.

Comment: But when I read in values from the console, don't I have to assign it as a integer or double?

Comment: Nothing in your question is related to reading values from the console. Please edit the question and show how reading values from the console comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, all the three input from the system are either integer or double. For other possible combination you can make necessary change in the code.

```
public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String str1 = br.readLine();
            String str2 = br.readLine();
            String str3 = br.readLine();

            if(str1.contains(".") && str2.contains(".") && str3.contains(".")){
                double a = Double.parseDouble(str1);
                double b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
                double c = Double.parseDouble(str3);
                max(a,b,c);
            }else{
                int a = Integer.parseInt(str1);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(str2);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(str3);
                max(a,b,c);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int max(int a, int b, int c){
        //Max code for integers
    }

    public static double max(double a, double b, double c){
        //Max code for double
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When call max(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) then compiler will automatically search below method

- max(double a, double b, double c)

When call max(1, 2, 3) then compiler will automatically call below method

- max(int a, int b, int c)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. How would I do that if was max(a, b, c) where a b and c are variables inputted from the console?

Comment: Those variables still have *types*, right? When you read `a`, `b` and `c` from console, where did you store them? In a `double` or in an `int`?

Comment: That is what I am not sure how to do. a b and c can either be a set of integers or a set of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I'd write one method that accepts Comparable arguments and re-use it for double, int (converted to Integer, Double by java behind the scenes) or anything else you need to compare to find max value.
Or (even better) use [ObjectUtils.max()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html) from apache commons-lang3
No reason to repeat the same code for multiple argument types (DRY principle).